# Can't launch an Android Emulator for Visual Studio

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, xamarin, android-emulator

Literally tried to fix this with several fixes provided in Microsoft forums and nothing worked and I didn't understand some things.

I'm trying to launch a test Xamarin Code and make it run on an Android profile but when I try to install it  stays at Copying .vhd files and creating a Virtual machine. [Here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GVVgS.jpg)

Then it prompts me for admin and it retries. It fails and give me this log file:

```
0> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] ===== Session Started =====
1> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager version: 1.1.622.2
1> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Emulator manager plugin version: 1.1.622.2
1> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.14393.0 Windows 10 Pro
1> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Virtualization type: UnknownOrNotVirtual
1> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Version: alaska - 1072009
1> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Serial Number: to be filled by o.e.m.
1> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Virtualization Product: z97 killer
1> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Display Adapter 0: Name: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970, Version: 21.21.13.7270
2> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 2
2> 9/9/2016 10:11:43 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installable profiles.
2> 9/9/2016 10:11:45 PM : [Informational] Installable profiles initialized. Devices: 38 Platforms: 5
3> 9/9/2016 10:12:06 PM : [Informational] Waiting to uninstall device...
3> 9/9/2016 10:12:06 PM : [Informational] Uninstalling Device: 10.1" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Tablet
3> 9/9/2016 10:12:06 PM : [Informational] Uninstalling virtual machine for 10.1" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Tablet
3> 9/9/2016 10:12:06 PM : [Informational] Removing device files
3> 9/9/2016 10:12:06 PM : [Informational] Uninstall complete
2> 9/9/2016 10:12:06 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2> 9/9/2016 10:12:06 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 0 Platforms: 2
4> 9/9/2016 10:12:08 PM : [Informational] Waiting to install device...
4> 9/9/2016 10:12:08 PM : [Informational] Installing Device: 5.7" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone , Version: 1.0.60404.1
4> 9/9/2016 10:12:09 PM : [Informational] Creating device configuration
2> 9/9/2016 10:12:09 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2> 9/9/2016 10:12:09 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 2
4> 9/9/2016 10:12:10 PM : [Informational] Copying .vhd files and creating virtual machine
4> 9/9/2016 10:14:12 PM : [Informational] Waiting to uninstall device...
4> 9/9/2016 10:14:12 PM : [Informational] Uninstalling Device: 5.7" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone
4> 9/9/2016 10:14:12 PM : [Informational] Uninstalling virtual machine for 5.7" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone
4> 9/9/2016 10:14:13 PM : [Informational] Removing device files
4> 9/9/2016 10:14:13 PM : [Informational] Uninstall complete
2> 9/9/2016 10:14:13 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2> 9/9/2016 10:14:13 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 0 Platforms: 2
4> 9/9/2016 10:14:14 PM : [Informational] Waiting to install device...
4> 9/9/2016 10:14:14 PM : [Informational] Installing Device: 5.7" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone , Version: 1.0.60404.1
4> 9/9/2016 10:14:14 PM : [Informational] Creating device configuration
2> 9/9/2016 10:14:14 PM : [Informational] Reinitializing installed profiles.
2> 9/9/2016 10:14:14 PM : [Informational] Installed profiles initialized. Devices: 1 Platforms: 2
4> 9/9/2016 10:14:15 PM : [Informational] Copying .vhd files and creating virtual machine
4> 9/9/2016 10:15:27 PM : [Critical] An internal virtual network switch is required for emulated devices to run.
4> 9/9/2016 10:15:27 PM : [Critical] XDE Path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft XDE\10.0.10586.0\xde.exe
4> 9/9/2016 10:15:27 PM : [Critical] XDE Arguments: /sku Android /displayName "VS Emulator 5.7\" Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone" /memSize 3072 /diagonalSize 5.7 /video "1440x2560" /vhd "C:\Users\lbthe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudioEmulator\Android\Containers\Local\Devices\vhd\5.7_Marshmallow_(6.0.0)_XHDPI_Phone\image.vhd" /name "VS Emulator 5.7-inch Marshmallow (6.0.0) XHDPI Phone.lbthe" /noStart /silent
4> 9/9/2016 10:15:27 PM : [Critical] XDE Exit Code: CouldntCreateInternalSwitch (16)
```

I read that I should create an Internal Switch and an External switch. I could successfully make an Internal one but when I try to make an External one [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYf63.jpg) happens.

Using Windows 10 Pro if thats useful for anything, if you need more information I will gladly provide it.

Comment: Seems you have problem with Hyper-V which fails to create virtual network switch

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before. You can always recheck to see if you have developer mode to set to true. Go to your settings-> Update -> then Developer ensure that the Developer Mode is turned on. Then Also you need to make sure your computer is Hyper-V enabled through the BIOS sometimes they are turned off. If you dont have the Hyper-V capability then your pretty much out of luch using emulators. You would have to the next best thing. Install it on a test android phone.

this link may be useful

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2015/07/20/using-the-visual-studio-emulator-for-android-from-android-studio-or-eclipse-with-adt/

Comment: Just enabled Developer mode in the Windows settings and I am still getting stuck here: http://imgur.com/o5epAL7

And my pc is Hyper-V compatible, I've checked various ways like Coreinfo,   and intels processor identification utlity.

Comment: Developer Mode on Windows 10 has nothing related with Android development and Xamarin.

Comment: I called Microsoft and they said the only work around was to use a sync cable and register the phone in my Microsoft Dev Account. They also said make developer mode is enabled They also told me to re install the emulators... Re-Installing windows will not do anything. If you have 5 hyper-v selections in bios and 4 are able to be activated then the emulators won't work because all 5 are not active. Try running the windows phone emulator.. If you have a problem then your computer is not fully Hyper-V capable.. If windows phone does work then it could be a bad download with the android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem before and I need to re-install Windows

Comment: I might have to do this but the problem is I have half a terabyte of data I need, not just for coding that I don't want to erase to clean install. Would be too much of a hassle but it will be the final step if nothing else works.